# JPA-Hibernate persist data which didn't save

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When a Object read from the DB and edited that but on saving process i take a decision whether to save or discard the data. But JPA/Hibernate automatically saves the edited data(Auto Flush).

```
DB.beginTransaction
try{
     MyObject myObj = DB.readMyObject();
     myObj.setCurrentTime(System.currentTimeinMills());

     MyObject myObj1 = DB.readMyObject();
     myObj1.setCurrentTime(System.currentTimeinMills());

        // myObj Edited.
        // myObj1 Edited.

     if(isPermittedToSave()){
          DB.persist(myObj);
     }
     DB.persist(myObj1);

     DB.commitTransaction();
} Catch(Exception e) {
    DB.rollbackTransaction();
}
```

I will persist "myObj1" always. All these process must be run under a single transaction.

What should i do to disable this behavior of JPA/Hibernate. The solution should also able to do Lazy Fetch and update "myObj".

Answer (score 0):

> i take a decision whether to save or discard the data.

This is where long running transactions will come in handy. If you decide to persist your changes - commit the transaction. If you decide to discart changes - rollback the transaction.

Auto flush settings are not relevant here. Auto commit on the other hand needs to be disabled.

Comment: dear @Antoniossss thanks for your fast reply. Can u suggest me solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Just begin transaction, do your work, and then commit if you want to persist the changes or rollback if you want to discard them.